# Angularjs 2 with php environment..?

Tags: php, angular

1) Can I create project in `php` with `angularjs 2`?

2) Can I setup `Angularjs 2` environment with `php`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A question should contain the information what you tried and where you failed. There are already questions with answers about how to deploy Angular2 applications. There are no specifics to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is used for backend development while Angular.js is used for frontend development.
You can use this combination, because angular will use methods for get, post, delete... with the URLs that you will create with PHP.

Here you have an example:
http://4dev.tech/2016/07/using-http-client-to-integrate-angular2-to-php/

Basically with PHP create a JSON file and with Angular2, it makes a GET call to the php url to obtain the JSON.